# PHP explode to array but only behind a character

Tags: php

I have some numbers like that (string)

```
1634996266;173.39,1635550011;270.28,1635961833;32.99
```

I need that number between ; and , in an array...

I found that `print_r(explode(",",$row["pricehistory"]));` to get it into an array, but i doesnt find a way, how to delete everything before this `;` character

This is how my array looks like as an example:

```
Array ( [0] => 1634996266;173.39 [1] => 1635550010;270.28 [2] => 1635961833;32.99 )
```

But i need like that

```
Array ( [0] => 173.39 [1] => 270.28 [2] => 32.99 )
```

i tried few things but i doesnt get that deleted before that character `;`

Comment: `print_r(explode(";",$row["pricehistory"]));` probably is what you are looking for

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin no... than i have this `Array ( [0] => 1634996266 [1] => 173.39,1635550010 [2] => 270.28,1635961833 [3] => 32.99 )` ... but not like what i need above :( Dont need the long number before `;` but behind... and this `,` is splitter

Answer (score 0):

After you explode on `,` character, loop through the array and explode each element on `;` and replace it with the second element.

```
$pairs = explode(",", $row["pricehistory"]);
foreach ($pairs as &$pair) {
    $pair = explode(";", $pair)[1];
}
print_r($pairs);
```